# How to undo changes in tfs coming from unmanaged workspace?

Tags: tfs, workspace, undo, unlock

I have a workspace that is lost forever. I have some files checked out from this workspace. I want to unlock them but I can't. I tried to do:

```
TF UNDO $/MyProject/MyFolder/MyFile.cs /WORKSPACE:LOST;user /s:http://mysite:8080
```

But I got this message:

> The workspace LOST;user is not on this
>   computer.  Run get (get all if edits
>   were undone) on the computer hosting
>   that workspace to update it with the
>   change s that have been made on the
>   server.

Does exist any way to undo a file (**not every** file) checked out by unavailable workspace?

Answer (score 5):

If the workspace is lost, then I would just delete it.  Deleting it undoes any changes that were made in it.

```
tf workspace /delete WorkspaceName;WorkspaceOwner
```

Comment: my real need is to undo a file checked out by a temporary unavailable workspace

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the appropiate permissions I would think that the method from this answer by @BubbleSort should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17870318/1982894
He used TFS 2012, I have tested it in TFS 2010 and it works there too.

Answer copied for easy reference:

> (Note: I have the TFS Power Tools installed so if you don't see the
>   described options you may need to install them.
>   http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f
>   )
>
> If you are accessing the Source Control Explorer as a team project
>   administrator (or at least someone with the "Undo other users'
>   changes" access right) you can do the following in Visual Studio 2012
>   to clear a lock and checkout.
>
> 1. From the Source Control Explorer find the folder containing the locked file(s).
> 2. Right-click and select **Find** then **Find by Status...**
> 3. The "Find in Source Control" window appears
> 4. Click the **Find** button
> 5. A "Find in Source Control" tab should appear showing the file(s) that are checked out
> 6. Right click the file you want to unlock
> 7. Select **Undo...** from the context menu
> 8. A confirmation dialog appears.  Click the **Yes** button.
> 9. The file should disappear from the "Find in Source Control" window.
>
> The file is now unlocked.