# How to unlock the TFS server files locked by other developer in other machine

Tags: tfs

Some TFS server files are checked out by one developer in eg (houbm10) machine in lock mode. After that the machine is changed with some other machine like houbm20, now I am unable to checkout those locked file.

So, how can I unlock those files?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451637/how-to-unlock-a-file-from-someone-else-in-team-foundation-server

Comment: hi! Rotem, but i m still getting problem `The item C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\References\AxInterop.OfficeCtrl.dll could not be found in your workspace, or you do not
have permission to access it.
The item $/S/B/P_AOT_2.1/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/UpdateUserResources/Dll could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To unlock individual files run the command below in Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
tf undo "file_path" /workspace:workspace_name
```

e.g.:

```
tf undo $/S/B/ABC/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/xyz/abc/Abc.dll /workspace:Houst01
```

here it will unlock Abc.dll which is inside abc folder.

To unlock the whole folder in one shot:

```
tf undo $/S/B/ABC/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/xyz/abc/* /workspace:Houst01
```

here it will unlock all files which is inside abc folder.

Comment: I successfully used your example but had to include the domain and username of the user who had the file/s locked after workspace. E.g /workspace:Houst01;<domain>\<username>

Answer (score 5):

Did you try the [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm) from Attrice?

It gives you a graphical interface to do all these commands, which makes it much easier to perform these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

try this in Visual studio command prompt i hope it will work...

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>tf undo
 {tfsfilepath} /Workspace:{tfsusername}

 Undo your changes to {Filepath} (Yes/No) yes
```