# TFS Web Portal - Document locked for editing by my user

Tags: tfs

This is more than likely a very simple question but I can not find the answer via any of my google searches.

I am trying to update a word document via the TFS web portal. I have tried via VS2010 as well and get the same issues. Once I attempt to open the document as "Edit", I get a notice "This file is locked for editing by MYDOMAIN\myusername".

Looking online, I have found several articles stating I need to delete the file on my workspace, but I can not find the file since it is not in the Source Control section of TFS.

Is there a way to cancel my lock on the file so that I can edit the file?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help anyone that may have issues with this in the future, I was able to correct this issue in Windows 10 by clicking on the icon for File Upload Center and canceling the attempt to upload the document.

Once I restarted my computer, I was able to open the file and edit with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS2010, you can try to undo anyone's checkout with the following command:

```
tf undo {file path} /workspace:{workspace};{username}
```

Details please refer this blog [How to force undo checkout? #TFS](http://fci-h.blogspot.sg/2011/01/how-to-force-undo-checkout-tfs.html)

---

You can also use the *Status Sidekick* of [TFS Sidekicks tool](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) and unlock the files which are checked out.

Detail steps you can refer the answer from *Tim Partridge* in this similar question [How to unlock a file from someone else in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451637/how-to-unlock-a-file-from-someone-else-in-team-foundation-server/14565165#14565165)