# How to solve Cannot lock item error for a file which don’t even exist?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I got a new laptop from a company with company image.

I created a new folder and check-in it – it is working

I check in few files , -- it is working

I cannot check-in DLL , SQL or JPG files , getting Error TF10151: Cannot lock item

It is happening to all the developers who got the new laptop .

Everything is working from an old laptop for the same developer.

Error : TF10151: Cannot lock item $/ABC/DEF/Some.dll for check-out. The item $/ABC/DEF is checked out by UserName in the workspace LapTop Name.

**And this error makes no sense at all. The folder is just created, How a developer check out the file which don’t even exist.**

If user Profile copied from old laptop to New Laptop , it is working.

Any Suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [unLock command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/lock-command?view=azure-devops) to remove other users lock for an item.

```
tf lock /lock:none[/workspace:workspacename] [/recursive] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
```

> To use the lock command, you must have the Lock permission set to
> Allow. Having the Unlock other user's changes permission set to Allow
> is required to remove a lock held by another user if you do not have
> Write permission for that user's workspace.

Or try to undo another user's checkout with the [Undo command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/undo-command?view=azure-devops):

```
tf undo [/workspace:workspacename[;workspaceowner]][/recursive] itemspec [/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]][/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
```

You can also refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451637/how-to-unlock-a-file-from-someone-else-in-team-foundation-server) for more solutions.

Comment: This has worked for me in the past. Just be sure you `dir /s` to find `tf.exe`. It'll be in a path such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`